# Using an unsupported library, leading me onto casting

Tags: java, casting

I have to work with this library that deals with a standard for biodiversity. Essentially, it reads in csv, xml etc and validates it, allowing one to iterate through the records with the type *DarwinCoreRecord*

For some odd reason, as soon as the object is moved from the iterator, it is gone. Small example below:

```
           ArrayList<DarwinCoreRecord> dwc = new ArrayList<DarwinCoreRecord>();
            for(; iter.hasNext();) {
            DarwinCoreRecord record = iter.next();
                    System.out.println(record.getSomeValue());
            dwc.add(record);
        }
```

That print statement is perfect and prints out the right details, if I out that print statement outside of the for loop, nulls are had by all.

So, onto my question (unless anyone can solve the above). I created a skeleton class that extends this DarwinCoreRecord. It looks exactly like this:

```
public class DWCRecordStore extends DarwinCoreRecord {

public DWCRecordStore() {

}
  }
```

This was just to test my plan would work but I am getting a classcastexception. It has been a while since I have dealt with casting (in Java, at least) but I see no issues. I am not casting from DWCRecordStore to DarwinCoreRecord so I cannot see the problem.

Does anyone see anything glaring that I have missed?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry, error is here:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.gbif.dwc.record.DarwinCoreRecord cannot be cast to com.encima.DWCRecordStore
at com.encima.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:37)
```

EDIT 2: Added my use of the casting.

```
DWCRecordStore drs = new DWCRecordStore();
            DarwinCoreRecord dwc  = iter.next();
            drs = (DWCRecordStore) dwc;
```

Comment: Done, have accepted all answers that helped the problem in part and added my own answers for those that were partially solved. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Can you give the *exact* error and its stack trace? (+pointing to relevant lines in the stack trace?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast `DarwinCoreRecord` into an `DWCRecordStore` - but the first is not an instance of the second!

Think of `DarwinCoreRecord` as a polygon and `DWCRecordStore` as a square, you can always cast a square (`DWCRecordStore`)  to a polygon (`DarwinCoreRecord`) - but not the other way around.

It might be that you are trying to store an object that was returned from the lobrary as a `DWCRecordStore`. But the library is unfamiliar with `DWCRecordStore`, it returns only `DarwinCoreRecord` objects, which are not `DWCRecordStore`.

Pinpointing the exact problem might require more code - how *exactly* did you use your new class.

**EDIT:** your last edit clarifies it, since `dwc` is not instance of `DWCRecordStore`, it cannot be casted to one.

An alternative might be creating a constructor: `DWCRecordStore(DarwinCoreRecord)`, and using:

```
drs = new DWCRecordStore(dwc);
```

Comment: This may only serve to prove my stupidity but I thought A could be cast when A is an extension of B. This just means that B cannot be cast as A. Is that right?

Comment: Not entirely, if `A` is an extension of `B` - and you have `B b = new A()` object, then `b` can be casted to `A`. However, if `B b = new B()`, it cannot, since `b` is not instance of `A`. What matters is `b`'s dynamic type. You can check what the dynamic type is using the `getClass()` reflective method or using the operator `instanceof`.

Comment: @ChristopherGwilliams: Look at my edit, based on your code addition, I could provide a better explanation and an alternative.

Comment: I was afraid that may be the case, the DarwinCoreRecord does not seem to be cloneable so I assume that I would need to implement the copy of each method in the constructor to copy it across? Thanks for your clear explanations thus far!

Comment: @ChristopherGwilliams: From what I can see, yes - if you need a `DWCRecordStore` object, you will have to create it in the constructor. You won't have to re-create all methods however, do not override the methods that do not need any changes from the original definition in `DarwinCoreRecord`.

Comment: Excellent, working on it now. Very grateful for your answer and explanations! Marking as accepted now.